# When I try to select columns from dataframe, it turns into atomic vector

Tags: json, r, dataframe

I have used this method before as on other data frames so I know it works. However when I have tried to convert this json data from an API into a dataframe an error occurs. I convert the json data into a dataframe and then try to select the two of the columns. When I try and do this however the dataframe turns back into an atomic vector? Any ideas here? the code is below.

```
out <- GET(url=query)
http_status(out)
json <- content(out, "text", encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

## Convert from JSON to Dataframe
criteo_RTA_df <- fromJSON(json)
criteo_RTA_df <- as.data.frame(criteo_RTA_df)
criteo_RTA_df <- criteo_RTA_df[, which(names(criteo_RTA_df) %in% c("siteName","revenue.value"))]
```

Comment: Are you intending to take the two columns named "siteName" and "revenue.value"? Are they both present in the data frame?

Comment: yes that is corrcet, i want to just extract these two columns from the dataframe. the two correct column names are stated in the last line of the code

Comment: Before the last step, what does `which(names(criteo_RTA_df) %in% c("siteName","revenue.value"))` return? It should return an integer vector of length 2.

Comment: In R the only way to select columns by name in my data is to use this code:

criteo_RTA_df <- criteo_RTA_df[c("siteName", "revenue")]
The actual name of the column I want is "revenue.value" however if i use:

criteo_RTA_df <- criteo_RTA_df[c("siteName", "revenue.value")]
I get an error "undefined columns selected", but if I select "revenue" then this selects, "revenue.value" and "revenue.currency". I have tried to use gsub to change the name of the columns, replacing "." with "_" however this did not work. Can any solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You might be better served leaving out the comma within the square brackets. Take an example:

```
new <- data.frame( a=c(1,2,3), b=c(3,4,5), c = rnorm(3) )
```

If we subset a single column with a comma, we get a vector:

```
> new[,2]
[1] 3 4 5
```

But doing the same thing without the comma, we get a data frame:

```
> new[2]
  b
1 3
2 4
3 5
```

Either of the above methods will return a data frame when more than one column is being selected, but if one of your column names is missing, you may get a vector returned. To be sure to get a data frame, use the second method above.

Further, your last line of code could be simplified to call the column names directly, rather than via `which`:

```
criteo_RTA_df <- criteo_RTA_df[c("siteName","revenue.value")]
```

Comment: The error is from "revenue.value"! When I display the name in the environment it says the column name is "revenue.value" however when i use colname, it says the name is revenue ....

Comment: I can select the column if i just say "revenue" however it selects "revenue.value" and "revenue.currency". however in the environment it says that there are only 2 columns, not 3! any idea?

Comment: In R the only way to select columns by name in my data is to use this code:

criteo_RTA_df <- criteo_RTA_df[c("siteName", "revenue")]
The actual name of the column I want is "revenue.value" however if i use:

criteo_RTA_df <- criteo_RTA_df[c("siteName", "revenue.value")]
I get an error "undefined columns selected", but if I select "revenue" then this selects, "revenue.value" and "revenue.currency". I have tried to use gsub to change the name of the columns, replacing "." with "_" however this did not work. Can any solve this problem?

Comment: It turns out that there is a dataframe in a dataframe, this is what is causing the problem